# ListBox with overlapping ListBox Elements only lets me select the newest entry

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

My Problem is pretty simple:

Whenever the newest created `ListBox` element overlaps the other elements I'm not able to select any the overlapped ones. If an older element is overlapping new ones I can still select them.

To show you exactly what I mean here are 2 screenshots:

[image]

As you can see the third element is currently 'selected' but the user still needs to click on the element to show an `Adorner` that enables you to drag and resize.

If you try to click on it this happens:

[image]

The newest Element occupies the whole clicking space and therefore it is not possible to select the desired element.

Is this normal ListBox Behaviour? Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You may want to handle PreviewClick event instead of the usual Click for each ListBox element

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately I am already handling the PreviewClick for each ListBox Element.